# duplicating table layout using div

Tags: html, css

I'm not too good with div for layout, instead i'm used to using tables. I want to know if anyone can guide me to using div as layout instead so my habit of using table would stop. So with that said, can anyone help me with creating two row with three columns using div? Anyone's help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have a name-value type layout you can also use DL,DT structures to organize them (not directly pertinent to the question at hand but still an alternative): http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/13/how-to-use-dl-dt-and-dd-html-tags-to-list-data-vs-table-list-data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many examples out there for `div` based layouts.

A simple Google search brings a ton of info:

http://www.google.ca/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=creating+a+div+layout

Here's a decent one:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/

And a comprehensive article that ties it all together.  Definitely read this:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that rows will pretty rarely be the problem using divs with CSS... it will almost always be the columns and "floating" them appropriately that will give you difficulty.  For tutorials on that, I've always been a fan of [floatutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/).  More specifically, for your case, they have a [tutorial on a liquid three-column layout](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0916.htm).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways of doing what you want.

Here are a couple of ways: http://jsfiddle.net/Cq4G3/14/

Just bear in mind the new display: table-cell, table and table-row aren't supported in anything earlier than IE8, so you're probably best off sticking with floats until the older browsers are dead and buried.